# Magnetic force direction

Tags: electromagnetism

Good day All!
while trying to solve this question
[image]

I used the right hand rule and according to it the Force should be directed outwards (pointing toward me)
but here is the answer that puzzeld me
[image]

I really don't get why it is down , and would feel very grateful if someone can explain me the reason
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: In the 2nd plot imagine that the source of the B field is the blue magnet. Given the loop current direction its equivalent dipole is pointing downward so its "N pole" is closer to the "S pole" of the blue magnet, hence the force is attractive downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that from the symmetry of the problem, there can be no force directed out of the plane of the page (i.e. it cannot be towards/away from you, as the components from opposite ends of the coil cancel out in this direction). We should also note that to find the direction of the force, we use the Left Hand Rule, not the right. Since the field points at an angle to the normal of the coil's plane, we will get a net force downwards (just show this using the LHR). Alternative methods to determine the force would be as the second picture describes, i.e. using magnetic dipoles.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the force on the coil is probably the magnetic Lorentz force law $$ \vec F=q\vec v \times \vec B$$ The current at any point in the loop corresponds to a positive charges $q$ moving in the current direction with velocity $\vec v$. Thus, at any element of the coil, you take the right-hand -rule for the cross product to find the direction of the magnetic force. Since the magnetic field is inhomogeneous and at the wire $\vec B$ is not parallel to the axis but inclined towards the axis, there is a force component pointing downwards so that in the sum over all elements there is a resultant magnetic force downwards on the coil.

Comment: Thanks a million to both of you, your answers are really great!

Comment: Sorry both of you gave me great answers, but each time i tried to accept them both as answer, it disactivates the other one

Comment: @AmaOuchen - You can only accept one answer, but you can up-vote more than one answer.